# How to detect what control triggers BeforeUpdate event in Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, audit-trail, beforeupdate

I have an audit trail that uses the `BeforeUpdate` event to track changes made on a subform using the following code:

```
`Dim USR As String
Dim TS As Date
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
Dim Ctl As Control
MsgBox "Here!"
Set Connection = CurrentProject.Connection
Set RecordSet = New ADODB.RecordSet
If Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Visible = True Then
    For Each Ctl In Screen.ActiveForm.RepsSubformX.Form.Controls
        If Ctl.Tag = "Track" Then
            If Nz(Ctl.Value) <> Nz(Ctl.OldValue) Then
            SaveToken = True
                With RecordSet
                    .AddNew
                    ![Part Number] = Screen.ActiveForm.RepsSubformX.Form.Controls("[Part Nbr]").Value
                    ![Record Identifier] = Screen.ActiveForm.RepsSubformX.Form.Controls("[Part Nbr]").Value & Screen.ActiveForm.RepsSubformX.Form.Controls("[Supplier Name]").Value
                    ![Rep] = USR
                    ![Time Stamp] = TS
                    ![Change Point] = Ctl.ControlSource
                    ![Change From] = Ctl.OldValue
                    ![Change To] = Ctl.Value
                    .Update
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next Ctl
End If`
```

The problem I am having is that is the user makes two changes there are three things recorded in my change history table - the first change to the record twice and the second change to the record once (this trend continues as long as the user never leaves the record). What I would like to do is be able to identify the control that triggered the `BeforeUpdate` event and pass it to the code above so it can check if only the control that triggered the `BeforeUpdate` event is different and skip the others that have already been logged. Alternatively, is there a way to prevent Access from seeing logged changes as new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has been staring me in the face the whole time... When I assign the `BeforeUpdate` event to each control, I can make it pass a variable to the function it calls to tell me the program what sent it:

`Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form![Pack Rank].BeforeUpdate = "=ToTracking(""Pack Rank"")"`

After that, it's a simple matter of adding an and statement when checking for changed values so it only captures the change that set off the `BeforeUpdate` event like so:

`If Nz(Ctl.Value) <> Nz(Ctl.OldValue) And Ctl.ControlSource = NameOfTrigger Then`

```
'Record Values
```

`End if`

Answer (score 1):

Forms and controls have [Order of Events](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx) :

> Similarly, when you close a form, the following sequence of events
>   occurs:
>
> Exit (control) → LostFocus (control) → Unload (form) → Deactivate
>   (form) → Close (form)
>
> If you've changed data in a control, the BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate
>   events for both the control and the form occur before the Exit event
>   for the control.

You may wish to read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197592

Comment: I understand the order of events, the problem is that since the code is sorting through all the controls corresponding to a record, it is finding the values that have already been recorded and recording them again. I need a way to get the code to only record the final state the controls are left in when the user leaves the record. I have tried to use the `OnRecordExit` event but I don't think it is supported in 2007. Following MSDN's example I used `Forms![PartsDatabaseX]![RepsSubformX].Form.OnRecordExit = "=ToTracking()"`

Comment: If you use the form after update event, I do not see why you should get duplicate values. The reason I posted the above, is that I suspected that you had the wrong event. I also posted a link that may help.

Comment: You weren't wrong about the `AfterUpdate` event triggering at the correct time. The issue is that the `Ctl.OldValue` isn't updated during this event so the current and new value will always be the same. And the link you posted also uses the `BeforeUpdate` event.